# How to display blog post's multiple tags in blog post's blade template using laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have two tables: **tags** and **blog_post**
each post has multiple tags stored in single column( seprated by comma).

**Tags Table:**

```
  tag_id   tag_name
    1       Health
    2       Beauty
    3       Fitness
    4       Yoga
```

**Blog_post Table**

```
  post_id   post_tags
    1         1,2
    2         2,3,4
    3         1,4
```

I need to get tag names according to post_id using Query builder in laravel.
like: if post_id = 1

```
Health,Beauty
```

if post_id = 2

```
Beauty, Fitness, Yoga
```

Comment: why you store  tag seprated by comma?? can't you store each in  seprate field?

Comment: because list of tags is long. A post may contain more than 50 tags.

Comment: ok but than also you can use pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

make pivot table for post_tag table and store post_id and tag_id in that table 
schema would be

```
 post_tag
  -id
  -post_id
  -tag_id
```

and using attach or sync method you can attach multiple tag to one post.

than you can retrieve data by using many-to-many relationship.

In Post Model make relationship for tag

```
  public function tags()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
  }
```

than retrieve tags

```
$productTags = Product::with('tags')->find(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to use  One To Many or Many to Many.But 
You Can Try Like This

Inside Your Post  Model

```
 class Post extends Model
    {
        public function getTag(){
            $s = array();
            $post_tags =  explode(',',str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$this->post_tags));
            foreach ($post_tags as &$value) {
                array_push($s,$value);
            }
            $tags = Tag::whereIn('id',$s)->get()->pluck('tag_name');

            return implode(",",$tags->toArray());
        }
    }
```

Inside Your Blade

```
<ul>
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    <li>
        {{$post->getTag()}}
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Or

```
<ul>

        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <li>
                @php
                    $s = array();
                      $post_tags =  explode(',',str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$post->post_tags));
                      foreach ($post_tags as &$value) {
                          array_push($s,$value);
                      }
                      $tags = App\Tag::whereIn('id',$s)->get()->pluck('tag_name');

                      $tags =implode(",",$tags->toArray());
                @endphp
                {{$tags}}

            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```